# RewriteRule expression not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite a URl to another, but the Rewrite expression is not working.

Ex. URL1: "`http://www.demo.com/de-ch/case1/?id=23`"

And

Ex. URL2: '`http://www.demo.com/de-ch?id=23`'

RULE: `RewriteRule ^(.....)([\?]|(.*))$ http://www.result.com/$1`
This rule gives follow result:

```
http://www.result.com/de-ch?id=23
```

But I just need the iso codes `http://www.result.com/de-ch`

What am I missing in the Regex?

Answer (score 0):

You can't match against the query string in the rule's pattern. The query string isn't technically part of the path. You'll need to use a `RewriteCond` and the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=23
RewriteRule ^(.....) http://www.result.com/$1?
```

Note the "?" at the end of the rule's result. That will remove the query string.

However, since you're not doing anything with the query string, you can just leave it out entirely and only have:

```
RewriteRule ^(.....) http://www.result.com/$1?
```

Note that this rule will cause the browser to get redirected to `http://www.result.com/de-ch` and if you don't have a resource that resolves at that URL, then you'll simply get a 404 or some related error.